# How to set media type of a webservice response in springboot?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I created a web service and I'll call another web service from inside. According to response media type that call from inside, I return my real response.

But whatever I do, all response returned as JSON object.

My web service class is;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/changeservicemode")
public class ChangeServiceMode {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response changeMode(@RequestHeader(value = "serviceUrl") String serviceUrl,
                               @RequestHeader(value = "serviceMode") String serviceMode) {

        IVirtualDocumentService docService = UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(IVirtualDocumentService.class);
        VirtualDocument documentByUrl = docService.findDocumentByVirtualUrl(serviceUrl);

        String mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;//I'll get media type from another response that will call above code in this point

        if (documentByUrl == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).type(mediaType).entity("This url not found on DB!").build();
        }

        if (SimulationMode.LEARN.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceMode)) documentByUrl.setSimulationMode(SimulationMode.LEARN);
        if (SimulationMode.SIMULATE.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceMode)) documentByUrl.setSimulationMode(SimulationMode.SIMULATE);
        if (SimulationMode.STOP.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceMode)) documentByUrl.setSimulationMode(SimulationMode.STOP);

        docService.save(documentByUrl);
        String entity = "url: " + serviceUrl + ", mode: " + documentByUrl.getSimulationMode();

        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(entity).type(mediaType).build();
    }
}
```

here is my response;

```
{
    "context": {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": [
                {
                    "type": "application",
                    "subtype": "xml",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "wildcardSubtype": false,
                    "wildcardType": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "entity": "url: http://localhost:8066/virtual/wsapi/personelvirtual/getallpersonels, mode: SIMULATE",
        "entityType": "java.lang.String",
        "entityAnnotations": [],
        "entityStream": {
            "closed": false,
            "committed": false
        },
        "length": -1,
        "language": null,
        "location": null,
        "lastModified": null,
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 . continue..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify this property

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
```

for the `@RequestMapping` you have set for `changeMode` method. According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--), it should do what you want.

Comment: I changed it what your said, but now I got 406 status error and there is no anything shown. 406 not acceptable this request resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable

Comment: OK!. it is not about our webservice, it is about client headers (accept:xml,text,json..) thank you!